# Using Itunes connect lookup api's in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to get latest app version information in itunesConnect/App-Store. So may I use itunesconnect api "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=xyz......" in iOS app.
As in apple review guidelines

> 12. Scraping and aggregation
>
> 12.1.    Apps that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple
>   Developer Programs, etc.) or create rankings using content from Apple
>   sites and services will be rejected.

So this api will only be used at server side or I can also use in iOS app. Please reply.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the API in your app code easily because it is not a scraping. It's an official API.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect actually features a JSON API which you can use to change/read almost anything. I collected various API endpoints on a git repo: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put that into your app, but it's fine to run on your server or local machine.